# Problem with concavity

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck with part b of the following problem about derivatives and concavity.

Problem:

> Let $f$ be $f:R\rightarrow R$ such that for all $x$, $f(x)<0$ and $f'(x)<0$.

If $g(x)=\frac{1+f(x)}{f(x)}$

a) Prove that g is increasing.
b) Has g any inflection point? Analyze the intervals where g is concave up and down.
I've proved that g is increasing by analyzing it's derivative:
$g'(x)=\frac{-f'(x)}{f²(x)}$
which is always positive because f² is always positive and -f' is also always positive.

But when I analize its second derivative in order to analize its concavity:
$g''(x)=\frac{2.f'²(x)-f(x).f''(x)}{f³(x)}$
I don't really know what to do with f''(x)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe you can rewrite g'' in terms of g and g' ? Maybe it becomes easier to see then.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two cases:

1. $f(x)=-e^x$. Then $g$ has no inflection points and is concave on the whole $\Bbb R$.
2. $f(x)=-\arctan x -2$. Then $g$ has an inflection point and it's concave on one interval and convex on the other.

These examples show that the existence of inflection points depends on the choice of $f$.